# Displaying raw pixel array on a web page using image tag

Tags: html, css, image-processing, png, jpeg

I am trying to figure out the best way to put a raw pixel array into an image tag.  The pixels are served from a server that does not have a png or jpg compression library so the raw array comes in via an HTTP request. I can control the return headers so I put a mime type in the response.  I'd like to do:

```
<img src="http://myserver.com/id/" />
```

But I don't think I can do that.  I could use the src="data:XXXXXX;base64,http://myserver.com/id/" if that works, but I need to know what to do with XXXX.

Another idea I've had is using svg if I can set an image equal to SVG. Not sure if i'd have to wrap each pixel in an element.

Maybe there is a way to do this with CSS?

I can write the data to canvas element with js pretty easily, but I was hoping to have a non-js way.

I can do some minor manipulation of the binary structure of the data coming out of the server, so if there is an easy way to tell the jpg or png format that this is uncompressed data, I could do that...I just don't have the horsepower or the time to translate to the png or jpg libraries to the (blockchain) based language I'm having to use.

Comment: What's the format of the raw pixel array?

Comment: RGBA over and over. Four bytes for each pixel. You need to know the height and width separately.

Comment: @AustinFatheree please see my example when you have a chance. I see from your previous comment that the pixel data you are receiving comes in RGBA format with four bytes per pixel (e.g. R, G, B, A). If you can provide a sample of the data returned, I can refactor my example to use the RGBA values returned directly. It should actually be easier, as I believe I can plug them directly into the `rgba(r, g, b, a)` CSS function without having to convert them to hex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relevant links: the [zlib RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt), the [DEFLATE RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1951), and the [PNG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/). You may wish to consult these while reading.

Let's make a PNG!
Start with the image data as an RGBA image, for example for a 2x2 image:

```
12 34 56 78  9a bc de f0
cd ef 01 23  45 67 89 ab
```

### Specify filters

For each row of the image, add a null byte to the beginning to set the PNG filter to none. For example,

```
00  12 34 56 78  9a bc de f0 # row 1 of image
00  cd ef 01 23  45 67 89 ab # row 2 of image
```

### DEFLATE encode it

While this is a compression format, we don't actually need to compress it! DEFLATE provides a way to encode data without compressing it (see section 3.2.4 of the DEFLATE spec). Find the length of the filtered image data from above as a 16-bit integer (if it is bigger than 65535, then split the image data into 65535-sized chunks, and do this step for each chunk). Create an empty array to hold the DEFLATE data stream. Insert that size as a 16-bit integer in big-endian format into the currently empty DEFLATE data stream. Next, append the bitwise inverse of the length. Finally, insert the filtered image data into the data stream.

### Wrap it in zlib

Next, we need to zlib-encode the data. Start with an empty zlib data stream, and insert 2 null bytes for the header. Next, insert the DEFLATEd data from above. Finally, insert the Adler32 checksum of the **uncompressed** data. Specifically, the Adler32 checksum should be created from the filtered image data.

### Wrap it in a PNG format

Finally, let's wrap this into a PNG. Replace the width and height values, specify the length of the `IDAT` chunk as the length of the zlib-encoded data, and replace the CRCs of the `IDHR` and `IDAT` chunks by taking the CRC32 checksum of the the chunk name concatenated with the data.

```
# PNG signature
137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10

# IDHR chunk
00 00 00 0d # IDHR length
73 72 68 82 # IDHR type
00 00 00 02 # width: COMPUTE THIS
00 00 00 02 # height: COMPUTE THIS
08 # bit depth: 8
06 # colour type: truecolour with alpha
00 # compression method: zlib
00 # filter method: normal
00 # no interlacing
55 55 55 55 # CRC: COMPUTE THIS from "IDHR" + data

# IDAT chunk
55 55 55 55 # IDAT length: COMPUTE THIS
73 68 65 84 # IDAT type
[zlib data]
55 55 55 55 # CRC: COMPUTE THIS from the "IDAT" + data

# IEND chunk
00 00 00 00 # IEND length
73 69 78 68 # IEND type
AE 42 60 82 # CRC (always the same value, doesn't need to be computed)
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need!  Let me run the traps on implementing it and then I'll accept the answer. Thank you so much for putting this together!

Answer (score 2):

> Austin, I see from your previous comment that the pixel data you are receiving comes in RGBA format with four bytes per pixel (e.g. R, G, B, A).
>
> ** If you can provide a sample of the data returned, I can refactor my example to use the RGBA values returned directly. It should actually be easier, as I believe I can plug them directly into the `rgba(r, g, b, a)` CSS function without having to convert them to hex.

I use this exact same process in my [console.draw()](https://codepen.io/brandonmcconnell/pen/WNOeYLp) tool, and it works flawlessly for me, converting raw pixel data into valid `<img>` tags on demand.

If you receive the pixels as an array of colors, you will either have to supply the function you use with the number of pixels per row so it knows where to wrap to the next lines, or more appropriately, use an array of nested arrays, one nested array per row of pixels. Then, draw the array of nested pixel colors to a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement), row by row, pixel by pixel. Finally, use the [HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) method to convert the canvas image to a Base64 encoded string which you can assign to the `src` attribute value of the `img` tag.

If you would like to display the final image pixelated, without any anti-aliasing, make sure to apply the CSS rule `image-rendering: pixelated`.

Here is all of this, put into action:

```js
const pixels2Base64 = pixelColors => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = pixelColors[0].length;
  canvas.height = pixelColors.length;
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  for (let i = 0; i < pixelColors.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < pixelColors[i].length; j++) {
      context.fillStyle = pixelColors[i][j];
      context.fillRect(j, i, 1, 1);
    }
  }
  const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1);
  canvas.remove();
  return dataURL;
};
const nyanCat = [["#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000"],["#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#000000ff","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000"],["#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#000000ff","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000"],["#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#ff1111ff","#ff1111ff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#eb4ab4ff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#eb4ab4ff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#000000ff","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000"],["#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#eb4ab4ff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#ffd29bff","#000000ff","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000"],["#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#fea4feff","#eb4ab4ff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#ffd29bff","#000000ff","#00000000","#00000000","#000000ff","#000000ff","#00000000","#00000000"],["#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#fea70aff","#fea70aff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#ffd29bff","#000000ff","#00000000","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#00000000"],["#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#eb4ab4ff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#ffd29bff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#00000000"],["#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#00000000"],["#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#48fe0bff","#48fe0bff","#48fe0bff","#fefe06ff","#fefe06ff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#eb4ab4ff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#00000000"],["#48fe0bff","#48fe0bff","#48fe0bff","#48fe0bff","#48fe0bff","#48fe0bff","#48fe0bff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#eb4ab4ff","#fea4feff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff"],["#48fe0bff","#48fe0bff","#48fe0bff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#fea4feff","#eb4ab4ff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#fefefeff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#fefefeff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff"],["#48fe0bff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff"],["#0eadfeff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#eb4ab4ff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#fea4a6ff","#fea4a6ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#fea4a6ff","#fea4a6ff","#000000ff"],["#0eadfeff","#0eadfeff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#0eadfeff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#eb4ab4ff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#fea4a6ff","#fea4a6ff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#fea4a6ff","#fea4a6ff","#000000ff"],["#0eadfeff","#0eadfeff","#0eadfeff","#7543feff","#7543feff","#7543feff","#0eadfeff","#0eadfeff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#fea4feff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#00000000"],["#7543feff","#7543feff","#7543feff","#7543feff","#7543feff","#7543feff","#7543feff","#7543feff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#ffd29bff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#00000000","#00000000"],["#7543feff","#7543feff","#7543feff","#7543feff","#7543feff","#7543feff","#7543feff","#7543feff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000"],["#7543feff","#7543feff","#7543feff","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#7543feff","#7543feff","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#00000000","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#00000000","#000000ff","#a9a7aaff","#a9a7aaff","#000000ff","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000"],["#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#00000000","#00000000","#000000ff","#000000ff","#000000ff","#00000000","#00000000","#00000000"]];
const img = document.querySelector('img');
img.src = pixels2Base64(nyanCat);
```

```css
img {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

```html
<img>
```